# Does Hibernate have a limit on extending inherited Entity classes?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have a Java application that is deployed using Spring-Boot. The application inherits JPA Entities several layers deep. I had previously used EclipseLink, but I am now converting it to use Hibernate. I am running into a problem that I had not had with EclipseLink.

I have "entity-d" that extends "entity-c" that extends "entity-b" that extends "entity-a". The inheritance goes 4 levels deep, and Hibernate throws an Exception when I start the application. If I remove the last Entity (entity-d) so that it is only 3 levels deep, then the application starts without the Exception.

Here are some sample entities that I put together to demonstrate the problem:

BaseEntity:

```
package test.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorColumn;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.SecondaryTable;
import javax.persistence.SecondaryTables;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import static javax.persistence.DiscriminatorType.INTEGER;

@Entity
@Table (name = "base")
@SecondaryTables ({@SecondaryTable (
    name                     = "second",
    pkJoinColumns            = {@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn (
        name                 = "id",
        referencedColumnName = "id"
    ) }
) })
@DiscriminatorColumn (
name                     = "item_type",
discriminatorType        = INTEGER
)
@Inheritance (strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class BaseEntity
{
    public BaseEntity () {}

    @Id
    @Column (
        name     = "id",
        unique   = true,
        nullable = false
    )
    private Integer id;
    @Column (
        name       = "item_type",
        nullable   = false,
        insertable = false,
        updatable  = false
    )
    private Integer itemType;
    @Column (name = "column_a")
    private Integer columnA;

    public Integer getId () { return this.id; }
    public void setId (Integer id) { this.id = id; }

    public Integer getItemType () { return this.itemType; }

    public Integer getColumnA () { return this.columnA; }
    public void setColumnA (Integer columnA) { this.columnA = columnA; }
}
```

SecondEntity:

```
package test.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.SecondaryTable;
import javax.persistence.SecondaryTables;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table ( name = "second" )
@SecondaryTables (
    {
        @SecondaryTable (
            name                     = "third",
            pkJoinColumns            =
                    {
                        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn (
                            name                 = "id",
                            referencedColumnName = "id"
                        )
                    }
        )
    }
)
@Inheritance (strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class SecondEntity extends BaseEntity
{
    public SecondEntity() {}

    @Column (name = "column_b")
    private Integer columnB;

    public Integer getColumnB() { return this.columnB; }
    public void setColumnB(Integer columnB) { this.columnB = columnB; }
}
```

ThirdEntity:

```
package test.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table ( name = "third" )
@DiscriminatorValue("3")
public class ThirdEntity extends SecondEntity
{
    public ThirdEntity() {}

    @Column (name = "column_c")
    private Integer columnC;

    public Integer getColumnC() { return this.columnC; }
    public void setColumnC(Integer columnC) { this.columnC = columnC; }
}
```

FourthEntity:

```
package test.entities;

import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("4")
public class FourthEntity extends ThirdEntity
{
    public FourthEntity() {}
}
```

Running the application throws the following exception:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enabled debug logging (start with --debug)


2015-06-24 21:33:05.868 ERROR 3761 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in test.Application: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
        at test.Application.main(Application.java:73)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.isNullableTable(JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.java:800)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.determineSubclassTableJoinType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3814)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createJoin(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3787)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.fromJoinFragment(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3739)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.generateSnapshotSelectString(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1791)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLateInit(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3991)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4015)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:481)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
        ... 21 common frames omitted

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in test.Application: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
        at test.Application.main(Application.java:73)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.isNullableTable(JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.java:800)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.determineSubclassTableJoinType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3814)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createJoin(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3787)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.fromJoinFragment(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3739)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.generateSnapshotSelectString(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1791)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLateInit(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3991)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4015)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:481)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
        ... 21 more
```

If I remove the FourthEntity class (or just remove the @Entity annotation from the file) then I can run the application without Hibernate throwing an exception.

Comment: Does it seem you have encountered one?

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter too soon. I've added more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've diagnosed the actual problem. It had nothing to do with the number or depth of inherited entities. The problem was that the last two entities were using the same Table while the Inheritance Type was JOINED rather than SINGLE_TABLE.

I was not able to figure out how to annotate the entities so that ThirdEntity had a JOINED Inheritance Type from SecondEntity, but also provided a SINGLE_TABLE Inheritance Type for FourthEntity. Instead I created a new table, "fourth" for FourthEntity that was identical structurally to the table "third". Then I had FourthEntity extend SecondEntity instead of ThirdEntity. It was not ideal to have two structurally identical tables, but it did enable me to get things working without having to modify any other code in my application.

Here are the code changes that I made:

I added an abstract class called ThirdEntityBase:

```
package test.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;

public abstract class ThirdEntityBase extends SecondEntity
{
    public ThirdEntityBase() {}

    @Column (name = "column_c")
    private Integer columnC;

    public Integer getColumnC() { return this.columnC; }
    public void setColumnC(Integer columnC) { this.columnC = columnC; }
}
```

Once I did that, I was able to have both ThirdEntity and FourthEntity extend the abstract entity while pointing to different tables:

ThirdEntity:

```
package test.entities;

import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table ( name = "third" )
@DiscriminatorValue("3")
public class ThirdEntity extends ThirdEntityBase
{
    public ThirdEntity() {}
}
```

FourthEntity:

```
package test.entities;

import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table ( name = "fourth" )
@DiscriminatorValue("4")
public class FourthEntity extends ThirdEntityBase
{
    public FourthEntity() {}
}
```

The lesson: Pay attention to Inheritance Types!